# IntelliJ IDEA Force Push into GitHub

Tags: github, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 14.  I have a project in a local GIT directory, and I have a corresponding repository on GitHub. The project has about 100 files, but when I initially pushed into GitHub, only about 5 files made it up there.  I now need to push the rest of the files into GitHub, but when I try to do that, IntelliJ keeps telling me "Nothing to Commit."

Is there an easy way to just select the project and push (forced or not) everything into GitHub?

Comment: Have you already added your files to the staging area using "git add <file>"? Otherwise, Git will consider that you have nothing to commit.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it manually:

```
git push --force
```

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push

If this does not work, check your .gitignore, maybe you are ignoring the most of the files.

Comment: David, yes that will work.  I was just trying to figure out if there was a way within the IDE to do something similar. Like maybe a context menu option somewhere that I've missed.  I have the "Allow Forced Push" enabled, and removed the items in "Protected Branches."  But even with that, the IDE still thinks there is nothing to commit... so I was just wondering if there was a way in the IDE to initiate something like the manual way you suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

"Nothing to commit" is a message that can appear when you're trying to commit, not push. To push the changes you've already committed, use the "Push Commits" dialog available as VCS | Git | Push...